# Trying to read .txt file as a 2D int array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

In my current project, I'm procedurally generating a 2D map represented by a 2D array, which is saved as a .txt file. Example for a square room map:

```
1 1 1 1 1   
1 0 0 0 1   
1 0 0 0 1   
1 0 0 0 1   
1 1 1 1 1
```

Whenever the player dies, I want to read this .txt file, subtract 1 from the position where the player died, and save it again as a different file. I tried using File.ReadAllText() and then splitting the text by new lines and whitespaces, I also tried ReadAllLines() and separating the lines into other arrays, but in both cases it returns index out of bounds. This is the code as it is now:

```
int[,] deathMatrix = new int[mapReference.width, mapReference.height];//always the same size as the map, in the given example it would be 5x5
        string input = "Assets/deathMatrix_" + mapReference.seed + ".txt";
        if (File.Exists(input))//trying to read .txt into "deathMatrix" 2D array
        {
            String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(input);
            
            for(int n = 0; n < lines.Length; n++)
            {
                String[] integerStrings = lines[n].Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int k = 0; k < integerStrings.Length; k++)
                {
                    deathMatrix[n, k] = int.Parse(integerStrings[k]); //index out of bounds happens in this line
                }
            }
            File.Delete(input);
        }
        else
        {
            deathMatrix = mapReference.map;//if file does not exist, simply loads map, works correctly
        }
```

The part where it saves a 2D int array is working correctly, I just need help with this reading and decrementing, because I'm currently unable to see why index goes out of bounds since "integerStrings" should be the correct size after reading. I hope i made my problem clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious why do you have "mapReference.height" and not lines.length?

Comment: They're supposed to be the same value, i'll rewrite, but the problem remais

Comment: please debug your application at post the content of `integerStrings` at each n-loop iteration. I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: In the n-loop, it returns simply "1". It returns 60 debugs with a value of "1" in the k-loop, because in the base program the map height is 60.

Comment: Why not load it into a List<List<int>>?

Comment: **Why** do you split on any of `' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'` ? why not only on `' '` ? What if there is a hidden trailing `\r` ? The result would be one empty string more .. I would also include a check `lines.Length == mapReference.height` otherwise you can stop immediately ...

Comment: for me it seems that your `mapReference` and the file content have different sizes. actually this: `int[mapReference.width, mapReference.height]` should be the other way around. first the rows and then the columns: `int[mapReference.height, mapReference.width]` can you please post a more realistic example?

Comment: @derHugo "The result would be one empty string more" the stringsplitoption will remove all empty entries. This should be not a problem

Comment: @MongZhu fair enough .. what about any other hidden control chars? I just don't see why only splitting on spaces is not enough ;)

Comment: @MongZhu they do have different sizes, but only because a whitespace is inserted after each number, but in the end, with map width 100 and height 60, 100 numbers are written per line, and 60 per row. I included the whitespace hoping to facilitate the reading process. I'll produce a better example.

Comment: I think the problem might be in the saving procedure. If you have a CrLf at the end of the last line stored, the ReadAllLines will read 6 lines instead of your expected 5.

Comment: "100 numbers are written per line, and 60 per row." this is confusing. so do you have 60 rows? or 60 columns?

Comment: @MongZhu, sorry, english is not main language, i have 60 lines and 100 columns, 60 height, 100 width

Comment: Thomas might be right, can you run this line: `int amountOfEmptyLines = lines.Count(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));` and tell us the result?

Comment: If performance is the goal, then I'd actually use a binary format with fixed-size records for each cell of your array.  The advantage is that you can then _seek_ to exactly the right address of a cell, load it (in binary format, without parsing it) and decrement it and write out just that portion of the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd hand this off, tbh; shooing data into a text form and back into C# object form is the job of a serializer library. Assuming you don't actually care about the specifics of what the data in the file looks like, because you are only ever going to load and edit it in C#, you can simply add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json, and do:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deathMatrix));

int[,] deathMatrix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[,]>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

A 3x3 matrix would end up looking like this inside:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

If your code is generating a map elsewhere, that other place will need to write the file like this in order for it to be readable by this process here. At some point if you want to store more than just an `int[,]` the serializer will take it in its stride. Maybe you'll have an array of map squares with buried treasure, number of deaths, type of terrain.. [For example like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Jk3w0)

If you do want the file to look pretty inside, you can ask the serializer to format it indented (lets say if you wanted to edit it in notepad, and have an easier life), or you could even load it into some editor that undertands JSON, format it, edit it, save it, and the serializer will *still* be able to load it, because it's more robustly delimited than the example file

Comment: On one hand I agree, because there should be some modular component responsible for serializing and deserializing the array.  On the other hand, I always have trouble controlling the details of serialization.  For example, the code you provided serializes the data in a *different format* from what was posted.  This may diminish the ability for the designer to edit or read the file, if that is important.

Comment: What was posted wasn't JSON, but I talk about this in the final paragraph; one of the advantages of using some standard format like JSON is that there are boatloads of editors out there that handle it; you can take some file full of ugly minified json and load it into Sublime text and hit Ctrl+Alt+J and bam, it's readable, you can edit it and save it as its readable version and *the game can still load it*.. This proprietary, limited format the OP is pouring hours into hacking away at will always be a time sink in such a regard because it's so proprietary and fragile and needs custom tooling

Comment: If you're struggling to control the details of how the data ends up looking after it's serialized I'd ask why it's such a concern that *it has to look like X* - you shouldn't have to pour hours into battering a json ser into e.g. writing 2D arrays out as N rows of M values; you should be able to write it as one long line, or with a return char after every value and comma or any other variation, and *it shouldn't matter* so long as it deser's again..

Comment: This is excellent! I actually do care about what the file looks like, as long as it can be easily loaded into any game engine, which is why i chose 2D array, it looked simple enough. JSON fits this as well i believe, I'll attempt this implementation. Thanks

Comment: JSON of course adds a lot overhead in characters and is significantly harder to read/edit manually if this is ever required ;) If not .. then why not just go binary in general? There would be no argument for going text based at all tbh

Comment: @derHugo Erm. "Adds a lot of overhead" amounts to a couple of characters here. Every space is a comma, every [] is \r\n. If binary was so great it would be the dominant data interchange format/bson would've overtaken json.. but it is not this way, nor needs to be when wordy human friendly text protocols can pass over compressed-to-binary channels. The dark ages of "everyone having their own proprietary binary protocol" were terrible. Open is the future

Comment: @CaiusJard Well that's opinions of course ;) but a binary could have e.g. `(2 + 60 * 100) * 8 = 48016` bytes (if we know the dimensions are fixed anyway we can drop the 16 bytes) and this supporting full `int`/`uint` range values. A text file in OPs format would already have `60 * (100+99+1) * 16 = 192000` bytes (16 bytes per character even in ASCII encoding and 99 spaces and the `\n`). Your JSON (2 + 60 * (2 + 100 + 99)) * 16 = `192992` bytes (2 `[]` then each line again `[]` and 99 `,` and still chars). And this is assuming that the latter two also ever only will have single decimal values ;

Comment: I have nothing against JSON or your solution .. all I'm saying is if it is not needed to be human read writeable then a binary would not only be smaller but also faster to load/manipulate/write ;)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code again and your comment

> have 60 lines and 100 columns, 60 height, 100 width

you are doing

```
int[,] deathMatrix = new int[mapReference.width, mapReference.height];
```

So the first index should be the split part, the second the line.

But then write to

```
deathMatrix[n, k]
```

I think it should rather be

```
deathMatrix[k, n]
```

since `n` iterates the lines => height while `k` iterates the split parts => width.